# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager is showing extra margin top and bottom

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, margin, grid-layout

I am using Recycler View and GridLayoutManager and it is showing margin at the top and bottom of the image here is what I'm getting:

[image: My output]

onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "in onBindViewHolder");
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(getUriFromMediaStore(position))
                .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY))
                //.override(96, 96)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
```

image_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/im" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_image_picker.xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/image_recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.myapplication.ImagePickerActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the following line in your **ImageView**

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Your image will use full height and width.